# Code editor hints a lot of undeclared args. how it works?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, arguments, optional-parameters

I saw that code editor shows a lot of kwargs that are not declared in class init method.
[Code editor hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUqG.png)
Because Entry init looks like that: `__init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw)`.

I tried to create it on my own, but failed. How does it work? Is it an extra functionality for some libraries implemented in code editors, or is it a trick that I can use too?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at "what is this", it's best to ctrl+click the thing and see for yourself where your IDE is looking. :)

So ctrl+click the init part of what you wrote and you should be brought to the source of that. You should be brought to a typeshed .pyi file.

**What is typeshed?**

It's a project to be used by type checkers and ide plugins to better check and hint stuff from standard library. https://github.com/python/typeshed

**What is .pyi?**

They are type stubs, specifically for keeping types next to code rather than in the code. They are used a lot with C extensions because you cannot Typeshed docs explains them the best: https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html#stubs

> I tried to create it on my own, but failed. How does it work? Is it an extra functionality for some libraries implemented in code editors, or is it a trick that I can use too?

The info about stubs describes how to make them, the docs also have a page with tools that help generating stubs easier - https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/writing_stubs.html

But in general, you should probably avoid using such nested and multiple inheritance* to need that many kwargs for this to be better than just normal type hints in the code.

*What I mean is: tkinter.Entry inherits from Widget and XView; Widget inherits from BaseWidget (->Misc), Pack, Place, Grid... Those kwargs are due to this inheritance